# grep: remove lines with the same number twice

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a .txt file and on each line is some amount of numbers. What I need is to filtrate these which does not contain the same number. So I want the output to be only the lines which have all the numbers different. I have to use command `grep`!

Example:

```
File_input:

1 1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5 6

6 6 6 6 6 6
```

What I want

```
File_output:

1 2 3 4 5 6
```

First and third lines contains same numbers so these has to be filtrated out.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: This is not clear. By "filtrate" do you mean exclude the whole line? What does your data look like, can you [edit] your question to include an example with 4-5 lines? Excluding subsequent lines with the same number isn't directly possible with `grep` (though I suppose maybe your professor wants `grep -Eo '[0-9]+' file | grep -Fvwf - file` though that exact command excludes all occurrences, not just the repeats) but a very easy textbook example with Awk.

Comment: We didnt learn about Awk yet. And yes exclude the whole lines. Keep only lines with unique numbers

Comment: Your professor wants you to apply back references; google that. They probably also want you to solve this yourself, as that is how you learn. It's still not clear if you mean the same *digit* or the same space-delimited sequence of digits - is `21 12` an example of duplicate "numbers"? Also, your exampls are all with adjacent duplicates - is `6 1 6` an example of duplicate numbers?

Comment: I mean the same digit.. Thats why i called them numbers.. so 21 12 are different numbers so this line should remain. The line 6 1 6 should be eliminated because 2 same numbers are in the same line. And now about why I am asking. We have this subject for 2 weeks and we learn just basic stuff. Commands like cd,ls head, tail. sort, grep, paste and cut. And I spent over 3 hours googling about it. And I cant find any solution how to solve it. Now im learning about awk because I think this is the only solution at the moment. But still I dont know to specified because I have never used awk before.

Comment: If you can use something other than `grep`, look into `uniq`

Comment: uniq compares the lines.. I need to compare each number in line..

Comment: @tripleee After a several hours i came up with this dirty solution.. Here it goes: `cat numbers.txt | grep "1.*1" -v | grep "2.*2" -v | grep "3.*3" -v | grep "4.*4" -v | grep "5.*5" -v | grep "6.*6" -v | grep "7.*7" -v | grep "8.*8" -v | grep "9.*9" -v | grep "0.*0" -v`

Comment: I think you do not want to remove `1 12` of `12 23`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your example:

```
grep -v "\([0-9]\).*\1" myfile
```

Idea is to catch any single digit `[0-9]` and store it `\(\)` and search for the existing same pattern `\1` on the same line. You can easily extend to any word made of digits.

Comment: Both `11` and `1 12` are deleted. I am not sure about the requirements.

Comment: @WalterA Yes spec is not clear but OP will now be able to dig further on this

Answer (score 0):

With the given input you can use

```
sed -r '/([0-9]+).+\1/d' File_input
```

You will have problems with suubstrings: 1 matches 12 and 12 matches 1.
ou can add word boundaries `\b` with

```
sed -r '/\b([0-9]+)\b.*\b\1\b/d' File_input
```